# How to clean Windows of the remnant left by installation/ uninstallation

Tags: windows, cleaning

It seems that my machine, after a while in operation, has gathered quite a lot of unwanted files and has the registry polluted, thanks to Windows Updates, Installation/Uninstallation and other computer activity.

Is there anyway to know what files can be safely deleted, or is there any tools that I can use to clean up my computer?

Answer (score 3):

After each uninstall, I run [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/), which is great for finding little errors left in the registry.

[image]

During the installation, CCleaner asks if you want to install the "yahoo toolbar", so watch out for that. Other than that, it's a great program.

---

What you are showing in your screenshot are Windows Update files, which can be deleted, but note that if you do then you won't be able to remove those updates. But when was the last time you removed a Windows update?

Comment: I did, once. Although that was way back past my Vista years in my Windows 2000 time :). As for Crap Cleaner: As usual, be careful with such tools. Almost the entire registry is undocumented and only Windows "knows" what's in there. It's not uncommon for such tools to destroy a system (yes, I've had that with similar tools before).

Comment: CCleaner is probably the safest way of removing these directories: Windows Updates installers.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the files inside my screenshot are windows update files

Answer (score 0):

You can safely delete these files however you will not be able to undelete any of the updates or Service Packs installed. You can also use the Disk Cleanup wizard to get rid of unwanted files on your machine, however it does not include the update uninstall files.